# missing ) after argument list while re arranging rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When I debug my code below ,I have the error of missing ) after argument list

```
function Update() {
  var returnSheet = 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rowCount = returnSheet.getLastRow();
  var rrCell = 'A' + rowCount;
  var rrCell2 = 'E' + rowCount;
  returnSheet.getRange(rrCell:rrCell2).moveTo(returnSheet.getRange("A2:E2"));
}
```

Comment: `getRange(rrCell:rrCell2)` what do you expect `:` to be?

Comment: @vlaz from A to E cells for the last row

Comment: You still have to quote them as a string like you do on the other getRange call: `.getRange( rrCell + ':' + rrCell2 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shilly found the answer

```
  returnSheet.getRange(rrCell+':'+rrCell2).moveTo(returnSheet.getRange("A2:E2"));
```